# Jenkins docker build with NFS pv hangs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, nfs

I have a jenkins pod running on minikube. This pod uses NFS persistent volume with Winnfsd server and is working fine. In my jenkins pipeline I can clone my github repository, but when execute docker build command it hangs and after 3 or 4 minutes this error is thrown:

> [Pipeline] sh
> docker build . -t localhost/myapp:1.0.1 --build-arg HOSTNAME=my.ingress.host
> ERROR: input/output error
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: exc for class: groovy.lang.Binding
> at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:285)
> at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
> at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
> at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:355)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
> at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:117)
> at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Jenkins version: 2.387.2

minikube version: 1.28.0

WinNFSd version: 2.4.0

P.D. When using standard pvc on jenkins pod the docker build command works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Winnfsd server does not have support for NLM protocol as stated in this post:

[General error: 10 disk I/O error](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd/issues/97)

So basically what I did was to add `nolock` to mountOptions in pv:

> apiVersion: v1
> kind: PersistentVolume
> spec:
>    ...
>   mountOptions:
>        - nolock
>        - nfsvers=3

After that the Jenkins pipeline worked as expected!